# Confused with BITWISE, I'm using MySQL

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

I think I need to use Bitwise with MySQL.

However, I'm confused with

```
SELECT 29 | 15;
```

returns

```
 31
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

I have been reading what I can understand about bitwise but I'm lost.

Comment: Wait, you ask how bitwise operators work?

Comment: I know, I wish I could go back to before the moment I realized why it's called a "mask" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in 29, the bits 16, 8, 4, and 1 are set.

In 15, the bits 8, 4, 2, and 1 are set.

"x Or y" (|) means: "set all bits that are set in x or y or both".

So, in 29 | 15, bits 16, 8, 4, 2, and 1 are all set.

16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 31.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Partially, so what if I wanted to find a bit within a number ?

Comment: You mean "is this bit set in this number"? Why, you would use `and`, like this: (x & 4). If bit 4 is set, this will return 4, and if it's not, it will return 0. This is because in 4, only bit 4 is set, and no others, and x & y means "set all bits that are set in both x and y". (edit) For example, (15 & 2) will return 2, because 2 is the only bit that is set in both 15 and 2. On the other hand, (29 & 2) will return 0, since there are no bits that are set in both 29 and 2.

Comment: Hmmm, so it was looking for 16 in a number I'd `select field & 16` ? So taking this further, the field value would return 16 up until the value became 32 because the higher number used would be 16 up till this point ?

Comment: @Jules yeah. Basically, 16 which is 00010000 `AND` with any number xxxYxxxx will either return 00000000 (zero if Y=0) or 00010000  (sixteen if Y=1). Now all the numbers from 0 to 15 has 5th bit (Y) off (0), so they will return zero, numbers from 16 to 31 has 5th bit on (1) so they will return 16. Numbers beyond 31 may or may not have fifth bit on so, you can't be sure. **Basically, `AND`ing with 16 (00010000) only says whether 5th bit is on or off**

Answer (score 1):

It's same as (if you do binary operation)

```
 11101 OR 01111 =   11111 = 31 in decimal
```

where `11101` is binary representation of decimal `29` and `01111` is binary representation of decimal `15`

suggested reads

- **The Binary System** http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/CS152/97F/Readings/student-binary.html
- **Bitwise Operators** http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html